# Is there a way to transform my query into a way that my client needs?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table structure:

```
candidateExamGrades
-------------------
courseID
examID
examName
candidateID
examGrade

candidateCourseGrades
----------------------
courseID
candidateID
courseName
courseGrade

candidate
----------
candidateID
candidateLastName
candidateDOB
```

Here is my working query:

```
SELECT
    c.candidateID, c.candidateLastName, 
    ce.examName, 
    cg.courseName, cg.courseGrade, 
    ce.examGrade
FROM 
    candidate c
INNER JOIN 
    candidateExamGrades ce ON c.candidateID = ce.candidateID
INNER JOIN 
    candidateCourseGrades cg ON c.candidateID = cg.candidateID
```

Results:

```
canidateID  lastName    examName                    courseName      courseGrade     examGrade
______________________________________________________________________________________________

991         Smith       Electrical Systems          Electrical           S          90.1
991         Smith       Power Inverters             Electrical           S          87.4
991         Smith       Secondary Power Sources     Electrical           H          89.9
991         Smith       Machine Safety              Safety               U          72.3
991         Smith       Emergency Procedures        Safety               U          68.3
```

But my client needs the data in this form:

```
canidateID  lastName    gradeBlock                      grade       
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

991         Smith       Electrical Systems Exam         90.1            
991         Smith       Power Inverters Exam            87.4            
991         Smith       Secondary Power Sources Exam    89.9            
991         Smith       Electrical Course Grade         S           
991         Smith       Machine Safety Exam             72.3
991         Smith       Emergency Procedures Exam       68.3
991         Smith       Safety Course Grade             U
```

So basically, I need to combine exam and course names and then the grades.

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server 2012+?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION (decompose and execute the 2 queries unioned separated to understand why)

And then a little trick to keep the order needed (ie first the exams of a course and then their linked course) by forcing the value of the courseid to a huge number for the non-existent exam of that course

That gives :

```
SELECT candidateID, candidateLastName, gradeBlock, grade
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c.candidateID, c.candidateLastName, 
        (ce.examName + ' Exam') AS gradeBlock, 
        ce.examGrade AS grade,
        ce.examID, 999999999999 AS courseID
    FROM 
        candidate c
    INNER JOIN 
        candidateExamGrades ce ON c.candidateID = ce.candidateID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        c.candidateID, c.candidateLastName, 
        (cg.courseName + ' Course Grade') AS gradeBlock, 
        cg.courseGrade AS grade, 
        ce.examID, cg AS courseID
    FROM 
        candidate c
    INNER JOIN 
        candidateExamGrades ce ON c.candidateID = ce.candidateID
    INNER JOIN 
        candidateCourseGrades cg ON c.candidateID = cg.candidateID
) T
ORDER BY candidateID, examID , courseID
```

Comment: I am getting the error `Incorrect syntax near '|'.` for both sub queries where it says, `(ce.examName || `

Comment: Try changing the pipes || to a plus sign +.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell sorry I tought Oracle syntax instead of sqlserv, fixed. Thanks Rick